# Can a creature grappling someone drop them off a cliff?

Tags: dnd-5e, grapple, forced-movement, terrain

The situation is like this. PCs having a fight on a battlefield with several very deep chasms. One of the PCs attempt to grapple an enemy, then moves with him into one of the chasms (bringing himself and his target down and potentially very much dead). Looking through the rules, I have found only the following info about grapple and movement:

> When you move, you
>   can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but
>   your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more
>   sizes smaller than you.

No other rules are preventing the PC from just moving into the chasm and dropping his enemy in it. Or at least I have found none. If I remember correctly, in previous editions there were some rules pointing out, that the victim in this situation is subject to some save or an ability check. That was my ruling during the game.

My question then is basically this:

**Is there any rules about what options the grappled creature has in case the enemy tries to push it into dangerous terrain, such as a long fall from a high height?**

I am looking for RAW answers, because I want to balance my judgments on at least some rule base (or certainty that there is none). My players are OK with my rulings, but I feel uncomfortable nerfing their strategies just because I feel it is wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**There is no *general* rule that grants the options that you've described**. Unless that creature has flying, hover, or some other special feature, it's going to drop like a rock.

That said, I'd treat this particular combat scenario as a trap, so the pushed creature gets to roll a Dex save (to grab the edge). If he is thrown farther than he can reach, however, then there's no save. ;)

On the note of your PCs' strategies: The grapple-and-shove tactic is perfectly legal. Just be sure to try it on them sometimes to "test" the fairness of your ruling. ^_^

---

Ok, I re-read the entry and noticed that the PC opted to jump into the chasm with the enemy. If I were the DM, before resolving this action, I would first advise the player that she has the option to move the enemy so that it is between the PC and the chasm, and then execute a Shove attack. This is resolved much like a Grapple, but the PC gets to push the foe 5 feet (into the chasm, if it's Medium) on a win. ;)

Answer (score 1):

One obvious option the grappled creature has is to grapple the PC!

Once the PC is grappled, their movement is 0, so they aren't going anywhere.

Comment: In a way, this has merit. This is **not** an option for that exact moment when I am being "pushed" into a chasm (it's not my turn). This is a **very good** option, however, in my turn *before* my grappler gets the chance to push me. ^_^