# Can I pick up and drop a person in one turn?

Tags: dnd-5e, actions, attack

I am playing a level 6 Barbarian (I have 2 attacks). I picked up a person as one attack and walked him over to a well, and with my second attack I want to drop him.  Can I do that all in one turn?

To clarify: my PC is a Loxodon with 50 feet of movement.  I "grappled" my opponent with my trunk.  I was right in front of him, took him, and went to the well 20 feet away.

Comment: How far from the well was the PC?

Comment: By "elephant", do you mean the Loxodon race from the Guildmasters' Guide to Ravnica?

Comment: @Davo Please see [this meta](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6533/should-users-refrain-from-answers-or-partial-answers-in-comments) for why your comment was deleted. Thanks!

Comment: @V2Blast yeah but there is an app that had a different name so I didn't want to confuse anyone so I said what the basic race is.

Comment: Also related: [What are the rules around picking up and carrying bodies?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/103496/what-are-the-rules-around-picking-up-and-carrying-bodies), [How do I grapple/drag an unconscious ally? Does he make a contested check against mine?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/125691/how-do-i-grapple-drag-an-unconscious-ally-does-he-make-a-contested-check-agains)

Comment: I want to know if I can do it in one turn.

Comment: @NautArch I already did, in the question. I was in front of him so none then 20 feet to a well. I have 50 ft. I'm not asking about movement, I'm asking if I can pick up and drop a person in one turn.

Comment: This isn't exactly what you're asking but very related and may have useful info for you [How many actions or attacks are involved in picking up and throwing a creature](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139573/how-many-actions-or-attacks-are-involved-in-picking-up-and-throwing-a-creature/139581#139581)

Comment: Heavily Related: [Is it possible to lift a grappled opponent multiple times on the same turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77355/is-it-possible-to-lift-a-grappled-opponent-multiple-times-on-the-same-turn)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is It Possible To Lift A Grappled Opponent Multiple Times On The Same Turn?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/77355/is-it-possible-to-lift-a-grappled-opponent-multiple-times-on-the-same-turn)

Comment: Purely out of curiosity, how did you get 50 movement? Loxodon's look like they have a move of 30 plus your unarmored barbarian movement increases by 10 to 40. Doesn't matter in this case (just barely!), but just wondering.

Answer (score 10):

### Yes, you can do this

As explored in [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70606/can-a-creature-grappling-someone-drop-them-off-a-cliff), it seems plausible that you can grapple an enemy and then drag/shove them into empty space so they fall.

If you successfully [grapple](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) an enemy using your first attack, you grab them and the following applies:

> **Moving a Grappled Creature.** When you move, you can drag or carry the grappled creature with you, but your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more sizes smaller than you.

So you can't move as quickly, but assuming there's a well within half your normal movement distance, you could get you and your opponent adjacent to the well. You can end a grapple whenever you like:

> The condition specifies the things that end it, and you can release the target whenever you like (no action required).

So there is no action cost to simply release your grab if you've got the enemy in a precarious position; you can obviously grapple, drag, and release in a single turn. Many GMs would balk at you moving your enemy over an empty space and then dropping them, though. In that case, you could use a [shove](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#ShovingaCreature) once you've got your enemy next to the drop in order to push them down it:

> If you succeed, you either knock the target prone or push it 5 feet away from you.

That would require the use of another attack, but as you have the Extra Attack feature, you've got enough attacks available to do that in a single turn. Luckily, it's also explicitly clarified you can [move between individual attacks you make as part of one Attack action with Extra Attack](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#MovingBetweenAttacks):

> If you take an action that includes more than one weapon attack, you can break up your movement even further by moving between those attacks.

So, as long as you've got enough movement available to get to all the places you need to be, keeping in mind that your movement speed is probably halved while you're grappling unless your enemy is really Tiny, your Extra Attack feature allows you to both grab and shove your enemy in a single turn.