# Can the Crusher feat push enemies off cliffs?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, forced-movement

One of the benefits of the [Crusher](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/crusher) feat from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* (p. 79) reads as follows:

> Once per turn, when you hit a creature with an attack that deals bludgeoning damage, you can move it 5 feet to an unoccupied space, provided the target is no more than one size larger than you.

One of my players asked to push an enemy of a cliff of sorts using this ability. Would this work?

The way I see it, empty air does not equate to an unoccupied space. I think of an unoccupied space as an empty space that they would normally be able to move to. Is this the case? Or can they really push enemies with no check as they please?

Comment: Empty air is quite literally the definition of unoccupied space - and a person can very easily walk into the space off the edge of the cliff willingly it's just not a very good idea.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: @Andrew On a map the space beyond a cliff might be marked as an "impassable hazard", or as some other kind of space that can't be entered normally, so it's not necessarily clear that such a space is "unoccupied" in the same way a space of open ground is. In any case, if you have an answer to a question, please write it up as an answer. Comments should be used to ask for clarifications or suggest improvements to questions and answers.

Comment: related: [shove off a cliff while grappling](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/70606/can-a-creature-grappling-someone-drop-them-off-a-cliff)

Comment: related: [using the shove attack near a cliff](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/139573/how-many-actions-or-attacks-are-involved-in-picking-up-and-throwing-a-creature/)

Answer (score 21):

### Sure.

The [Crusher](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/crusher) feat reads (TCoE, p. 79):

> Once per turn, when you hit a creature with an attack that deals bludgeoning damage, you can move it 5 feet to an unoccupied space, provided the target is no more than one size larger than you.

Let's break that down.

- **[Y]ou can move it 5 feet**: So the target has to be 5 feet from the cliff.
- **...to an unoccupied space**: So, there can't be anything flying in the space.
- **...provided the target is no more than one size larger than you**: If the creature isn't more than one size larger than you.

### Caveat

The DM has final say, and some DM's are more forgiving with things like this than others. Note, you built the map, so you gave them the cliff and you approved of them taking the feat (because feats are an optional rule).

Some DMs might give a target pushed off a cliff, as a reaction, the chance to "catch the ledge" with a Dex save. It isn't RAW, but it isn't unheard of either. It is important that when I've seen this done, it is applied equally -- given to both players and monsters. You see Matt Mercer do this at times on Critical Role.  I am also inclined to do the same for players but not monsters, as I set the terrain if I created a cliff I expect the players to try to use it to their advantage.

### Does "empty air does not equate to an unoccupied space"?

The [rules for spellcasting](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/spellcasting#AreasofEffect) make it clear that areas of effect and movement includes vertical space. Monsters and players can fly in the game given spells or wings. So those spaces in midair can either be occupied or not. A space is occupied if it has a creature or object preventing movement through the space. You can indeed shove or push a creature over the edge of cliff with forced movement.